# MATLAB - recompiled executable smaller than original

Tags: matlab, compilation, size, executable

I'm re-compiling code written by a colleague approx 2 years ago. The executable he previously compiled  from this code is 1900kb in size. When I compile it it's only 600kb. I would assume this difference in size means I'm missing files from the build, but all the functionality is there and the executable seems to work fine. My question is: has anyone experienced this before? And does anyone have an explanation as to why the size would change this much?

My colleague and I used different machines but the same OS (windows) and the same version of MATLAB (2012b 32bit).

Comment: how did you compile it?

Comment: Hi Dan. Used Matlab compiler v 4.18

Comment: Maybe the original compilation had support for more machines/OS, while the current compilation did compile to be used *just* on your machine. This will depend in the compiler used (gcc, visual studio, etc) and the options on it.

Comment: @AnderBiguri MATLAB Compiler does not really "compile" in the sense that it creates Machine Code like a real compiler but it merely encrypts your MATLAB Code such that it can't be modified. The MATLAB Runtime executes the encrypted MATLAB Code, like MATLAB itself would, only doing the decryption beforehand.

Comment: @esel true, I was thinking in mex compilation, apologies.